# Files disappear on server

Tags: php, file, cloud, paas

I have an PHP application hosted on [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/) and sometimes it need to generate some files and store them on the server. Files are saved with `file_put_contents()` or with `imagejpeg()` and `imagepng()` functions. After a while files became removed. Can you tell me why and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Could you first show some more relevant code? We are left guessing right now, really.

Comment: Are you using Platform as as Service (e.g. Heroku) for hosting? Many PAAS providers will delete dynamically-created files when you redeploy. For persistent file creation you have to use something like Amazon Web Services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many PAAS providers, including AppFog, do not provide a persistent filesystem. Generally, you can save files but they will be removed when you redeploy your application.

For persistent file storage, you are encouraged to use a cloud provider like Amazon S3.

From the [AppFog FAQ](https://docs.appfog.com/faq#persistentfs):

> #### Does AppFog have a persistent file system?
>
> Not yet. We're working on this feature, but in the meantime, the file system is volatile. This means that any changes you make to the file system through a web interface, including any admin changes and content uploads, will be lost on the app's next start, stop, restart, deploy, or resource change. Because of this, you should make any changes to the file system on a local development environment and keep media assets and content uploads on an external storage system like Amazon's S3.